# How to create a Weak Referenced Event Handler?

Tags: c#, wpf, weak-references

I am doing research on how to properly create a weak referenced event handler. Since WPF has already a solution for avoiding memory leaks with events, I decompiled the "WeakEventManager" class and spent some time on analysing it.

As I found out, the "WeakEventManager" class relies on creating and storing a weak reference to the target object as well as to the event handler delegate. Here are some code segments:

```
this._list.Add(new WeakEventManager.Listener(target, handler));


  public Listener(object target, Delegate handler)
  {
       this._target = new WeakReference(target);
       this._handler = new WeakReference((object) handler);
  }
```

I am asking myself if this simple solution would already be working or did I overlook an important aspect, since most other solutions I found on the Internet are complex and hard to understand. The best solution I could find so far
uses an unbound delegate. That is some kind of wrapper delegate that takes the event handler and event subscriber instance as a parameter (yes, it requires the event subscriber object to be passed in during delegate invocation).

You can find this great article here:

http://diditwith.net/CommentView,guid,aacdb8ae-7baa-4423-a953-c18c1c7940ab.aspx#commentstart

The "WeakEventManager" class doesnt't rely on knowing the subscriber class or any additional information. Beyond that it also works with anonymous delegates. Why do developers spent so much time on writing a solution that is not only working but also convenient to use, if a solution only requires them to store a weak reference to the delegate? What's the catch?

**Update**: Because someone downvoted this question (may be it is a little bit unspecific), I want to give a more precise question:

Is that source code above all it takes to create a working weak event handler? If not, what is missing?

Comment: You don't need to decompile framework .net assemblies, [Microsoft provides the source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/WeakEventManager.cs). That way you can see the comments in the code they provide too.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Unfortunately this time I couldn't go to the "ProtectedAddHandler" method. When I tried I always was redirected to the top of the page^^

Comment: Its on [line 253](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/WeakEventManager.cs,253).

Comment: "it also works with anonymous delegates" -- that's a meaningless statement. A delegate is "anonymous" only inasmuch as it references a _method_ that is anonymous; the delegate instance itself is exactly like any other delegate, and it requires no extra effort to support such delegates. Indeed, even an anonymous method is only anonymous method where it's declared; the compiler still gives it a name.

Comment: No it isn't meaningless. Since the solution based on unbound delegates requires the event subscriber instance as parameter to work properly you cannot simply declare an anonymous delegate because it may not be related to an instance. That is the big disadvantage of most Non-WPF-solutions.

Answer (score 7):

> did I overlook an important aspect

Yes, an important one.  You traded one "leak" for another.  Instead of preventing the event subscriber objects from getting garbage collected, you now prevent WeakReference objects from getting collected.  You are not ahead.

What is *also* required is a mechanism to get those stale WeakReferences cleaned-up.  You don't need them anymore when their IsAlive property returns false, you then remove it from `_list`.  But you have to check that separately, *some* code needs to take care of that.  An obvious choice is to check when an event is added or when it is fired.  But that isn't enough, since client code only ever adds at initialization and you can't get a guarantee that the event is consistently fired.

So *some* kind of scheme is required to do it later.  Anything is possible and nothing is quite ideal because it is a lot of busy-work with often not getting anything done.  Making the right choice is important.  And that certainly includes *not* doing this at all, it tends to be a band-aid over a design problem.

Comment: You are right. I didn't refer to that in order to keep a clear view on the "plumping code" that does all the magic. The WeakEventManager class contains a Purge method for this purpose which is triggered by any event source object.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the `WeakEventManager` is that it keeps a list of weak references to the target object of the events and a list of handlers it must call, but does not "tie them together" (as directly subscribing to events typically does), allowing the target to be garbage collected (and periodically checked so that the "subscribed" delegate list is emptied accordingly when the source is garbage collected).

This, which sounds easy, requires a lot of plumbing code, and that's all the `WeakEventManager` does (do the plumbing for you in an easy to use manner).

If you are cloning out `WeakEventManager` to your own implementation (or using the built-in) and it does that, then yes, that's all you need to do. If that's not what you are asking, then the question is unclear to me.

Comment: Though a WeakEventManager does have more logic than that required for the plumping, I am interested in the specific code responsible for making the reference weak. When you focus only on that specific code than it seems to be in fact that two lines of code (whereby the weak reference of the target object can be avoided because the handler references the target object). I am amazed because I can't believe that this is as simple as that.

Comment: I saw this a while ago, so I might be wrong, but I think `WeakEventManager` internally uses the [ConditionalWeakTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to store the "subscribed" delegates (or list of delegates). This way it can relate the delegates to the target object without keeping a strong reference to them, allowing the target object to be garbaje collected.

Comment: It really doesn't do MUCH more than that (it schedules the cleanups and invokes the delegates, in a thread-safe manner, but that's all, as far as I understand it). That's what I call "plumbing" :-)

Comment: Which role does the CWT play in creating a weak reference? In the .NET source code the handler is added twice. To a normal list as well as to the CWT.

Comment: The key storage is weak, so you store the target object as a key, and it allows it to be garbage collected. It's on the documentation I linked

Comment: Yes, that is written in the documentation. But what specific effect does adding the handler to the CWT have for the WeakEventManager. What would change if Microsoft didn't use it in the WeakEventManager class. There is this comment in the source file: // add the handler to the CWT - this keeps the handler alive throughout the lifetime of the target, without prolonging the lifetime of // Does that mean that without the CWT the handler would probably be garbage collected too early? My main question is if the CWT is essential for the WeakEventManager's functionality.

Comment: I'm afraid that if you have studied the source code, you have done more than I have

Comment: @DennisKassel CWT just allows the list of weak references to the event handlers to be collected when the event source is collected.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that source code above all it takes to create a working weak event handler? If not, what is missing?

That is the most important bit, the rest of the `Listener` class is important as well, not to mention the manual plumbing required to support this non-delegate event handler.

For instance check out `ListenerList.DeliverEvent` which is a bit more involved than the usual `Invoke` call.

Basically the normal event system assumes strong references so in order to use `WeakReference` you end up having to add a lot of the translation logic yourself as well as deciding how to handle events that never fire due to using `WeakReference`.